# Debugging an already deployed JAX-WS service in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, debugging, remote-debugging

There is a Webservice written in Java (using jax-ws api's), already deployed on server. Suddenly, it has started giving wierd results, for some HTTP requests, that I could not reproduce on my local-box. Is it possible that I fire the HTTP request on the same server, and start debugging the code on eclipse installed on my local box.

Please help me with the steps for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On what application server are deployed your web service ?

You need to enable remote debug on your Tomcat, JBoss, Websphere, whatever application server, and just need to create a remote debug task in eclipse to connect on the right ip/port.

This is all you have to do.

To activate remote debugging for your application server, just add the following line to the JAVA_OPTS: `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n`

For eclipse you can follow [this link](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html)

Comment: The application server is Apache Tomcat. But, since its production server, I cant make any changes there on its settings.

Comment: Although, if there is some command like the one that allows to run a jar and debug remotely - i would be damn happy. I read about java -jar <jarname> -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000

Comment: If the server was not already configured for remote debug, I don't know if this is actually doable.